# How to use ruby gsub Regexp with many matches?

Tags: ruby, regex, csv, gsub, string-substitution

I have csv file contents having double quotes inside quoted text

```
test,first,line,"you are a "kind" man",thanks
again,second,li,"my "boss" is you",good
```

I need to replace every double quote not preceded or succeeded by a comma by ""

```
test,first,line,"you are a ""kind"" man",thanks
again,second,li,"my ""boss"" is you",good
```

so " is replaced by ""

I tried

```
x.gsub(/([^,])"([^,])/, "#{$1}\"\"#{$2}")
```

but didn't work

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Your regex needs to be a little more bold, in case the quotes occur at the start of the first value, or at the end of the last value:

```
csv = <<ENDCSV
test,first,line,"you are a "kind" man",thanks
again,second,li,"my "boss" is you",good
more,""Someone" said that you're "cute"",yay
"watch out for this",and,also,"this test case"
ENDCSV

puts csv.gsub(/(?<!^|,)"(?!,|$)/,'""')
#=> test,first,line,"you are a ""kind"" man",thanks
#=> again,second,li,"my ""boss"" is you",good
#=> more,"""Someone"" said that you're ""cute""",yay
#=> "watch out for this",and,also,"this test case"
```

The above regex is using negative lookbehind and negative lookahead assertions (anchors) available in Ruby 1.9.

- `(?<!^|,)` — immediately preceding this spot there must not be either a start of line (`^`) or a comma
- `"` — find a double quote
- `(?!,|$)` — immediately following this spot there must not be either a comma or end of line (`$`)

As a bonus, since you didn't actually capture the characters on either side, you don't need to worry about using `\1` correctly in your replacement string.

*For more information, see the section "Anchors" in the [official Ruby regex documentation](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/doc/regexp.rdoc).*

---

However, for the case where you *do* need to replace matches in your output, you can use any of the following:

```
"hello".gsub /([aeiou])/, '<\1>'            #=> "h<e>ll<o>"
"hello".gsub /([aeiou])/, "<\\1>"           #=> "h<e>ll<o>"
"hello".gsub(/([aeiou])/){ |m| "<#{$1}>" }  #=> "h<e>ll<o>"
```

You can't use String interpolation in the replacement string, as you did:

```
"hello".gsub /([aeiou])/, "<#{$1}>"
 #=> "h<previousmatch>ll<previousmatch>"
```

…because that string interpolation happens once, *before* the `gsub` has been run. Using the block form of `gsub` re-invokes the block for each match, at which point the global `$1` has been appropriately populated and is available for use.

---

**Edit**: For Ruby 1.8 (why on earth are you using that?) you can use:

```
puts csv.gsub(/([^,\n\r])"([^,\n\r])/,'\1""\2')
```

Comment: Cool, I tried to figure out how to do negative lookbehind assertions in Ruby and couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Thanks Phrogz, it works great with ruby 1.9 only, can you advise an answer for ruby 1.8?

Comment: @MahmoudKhaled Updated to work with Ruby 1.8. (In the future, if you have a need for such an ancient version of Ruby, please include this in your question. Ruby 1.9.1—the first stable version of the 1.9 series—was released over three **years** ago.)

Comment: @Rivenfall Correct. That is what I said: _"You **can't** use String interpolation in the replacement string"_. Did you mean to comment on the original question? Or did you misread this answer?

Comment: sorry I misread the answer. I'll add that \0 is the input string (but not $0)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming `s` is a string, this will work:

```
puts s.gsub(/([^,])"([^,])/, "\\1\"\"\\2")
```

Comment: When you're using double quotes in the content, it's probably better to use single quotes to enquote them like `'\1""\2'` or use the third form `%q[\1""\2]`

Comment: I'm a little bit worried that my answer won't actually be adequate for your situation because it doesn't handle lots of things, like if there actually is a comma next to a quote in your data.  You might need to do something more complicated that is not based on regex.