# How to reformat CSV file to match proper CSV format

Tags: ruby, csv, openoffice.org, fastercsv

I have a web application that parse users uploaded csv files.

Some users upload csv files don't match proper csv format mentioned [here](http://creativyst.com/Doc/Articles/CSV/CSV01.htm)

For example:

```
abc,hello mahmoud,this is" description, bad
```

This should be

```
abc,hello mahmoud,"this is"" description", bad
```

When I used ruby **fastercsv** library to parse the wrong csv, it **fails**. However, it **success** when I open the file by **excel or openoffice**.

Is there any ruby library can reformat the csv text to put it in a proper format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://fastercsv.rubyforge.org/):

> What you don‘t want to do is feed FasterCSV invalid CSV. Because of
>   the way the CSV format works, it‘s common for a parser to need to read
>   until the end of the file to be sure a field is invalid. This eats a
>   lot of time and memory.
>
> Luckily, when working with invalid CSV, Ruby‘s built-in methods will
>   almost always be superior in every way. For example, parsing
>   non-quoted fields is as easy as:
>
> data.split(",")

This would give you an array. If you really want valid CSV (f.e. because you rescued the MalformedCSVError) then there is... fasterCSV!

```
require 'csv'
str= %q{abc,hello mahmoud,this is" description, bad}
puts str.split(',').to_csv 
#=> abc,hello mahmoud,"this is"" description", bad
```

Comment: this fixes the unquoted problem but what if the csv file is malformed for another reason that can be fixed by openoffice also? Fore example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9098759/how-to-use-ruby-gsub-regexp-with-many-matches/9099705#9099705 Is there a generic solution for all these problems?

Comment: just for clarification. fastercsv was an external library in ruby 1.8 and was then included as the csv standard library in ruby 1.9.